# Why are there no down votes for comments

Tags: feature-request

Why are there no down votes for comments as there are for questions and answers. People sometimes use the comments to give answers as well.

Comment: There has been debates about this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/allow-downvoting-comments. By the way, this kind of questions regarding the way stackexchange works should be addressed on the main meta, because it isn't specific to the electronics site.

Comment: I mean, if you find a comment something that is not appropriate according to the rules or if they're completely off topic and/or not helpful and you feel the need to want to implement some down vote system for comments, you can always flag the comment to get rid of it completely. (Wow that's a long sentence, sorry about that but it was the best way to explain it haha)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because people should not give answers in the comment section. Such answers should be flagged and deleted, not downvoted.

Comments on Stack Exchange are an afterthought and essentially a "second hand citizen". As you can see when you try to write one, the clarification iterates that they are for asking for clarification and explicitly *not* for answering. You can not accept a comment as the right answer, and you can not edit mistakes in it. They can also be removed at any time.

Answer (score 2):

This is site wide (through all of SE's networks) and is not going to change as it would affect all sites. This has already been covered here in the meta:

[Allow downvoting comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3615/allow-downvoting-comments)